# array_unique with two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays of the same length `($search_type, $search_term)`.  I want to remove any duplicates in the sense of there being searches that have the same type and search term (ie `$search_type[$a] == $search_type[$b] && $search_term[$a] == $search_term[$b]`).

I'm aware that I could write this using loops, was wondering if there's a simpler (but equally efficient) way that takes advantage of built in functions?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the two arrays?

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: @Casey Hope: nope, no need to preserve

Comment: `array_intersect()`? Compare array1 against array2 then array2 against the result... it checks for type I believe.

Comment: Any chance of _not_ having two separate arrays for this but instead something like `array( array('term'=>'foo', 'type'=>'x'), array('term'=>'bar', 'type'=>'y'), ... )` ?

Comment: VolerK, I receive them as two different arrays from $_GET.. I was thinking one way of doing this would be to convert it to an array like that.. would that be efficient?

Comment: You could use `array_unique()` then. Do you have influence on the thingy that sends those values, i.e. can you change the parameter names? In that case you could let php do the work of combining all those parameters into one array.

Comment: volkerK: nah, the way things work client side it's easier to send as an array.  but if you write the code for making the array and then running array_unique ill accept the answer

Comment: Will either `$search_type` or `$search_term` contain duplicates -- in other words, will there be something like `$search_type = array(1, 3, 3, 3)` or `$search_term = array('hello', 'world', 'hello')`?

Comment: If you're getting these from `$_GET`, you can make the form values easier to work with. Instead of `search_type[]` and `search_term[]`, you might be able to output `search[0][type]`, `search[0][term]`, `search[1][type]`, `search[1][term]`, etc., after which you will be able to simply call `array_unique`.

Answer (score 0):

Try either [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/array_intersect) which will take two arrays and return an array where a value in array A exists in array B. Or [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/array_diff) which does the opposite and returns an array of all values in A that don't exist in B.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's an overly complex ad-hoc `function foo()` (lacking error handling, documentation and testing) that combines those two arrays. array_unique() takes care of the duplicates.

```
<?php
$search_term = array('termA', 'termB', 'foo'=>'termC', 'bar'=>'termD', 'termB', 'termA');
$search_type= array('typeA', 'typeB', 'foo'=>'typeC', 'bar'=>'typeD', 'typeB', 'typeA');

$x = foo(array('term', $search_term), array('type', $search_type));
$x = array_unique($x, SORT_REGULAR);
var_dump($x);

function foo() {
  $rv = array();
  $params = func_get_args();
  foreach ( array_keys($params[0][1]) as $key ) {
    $rv[$key] = array();  
    foreach( $params as $p ) {
      $rv[$key][$p[0]] = $p[1][$key];  
    }
  }
  return $rv;
}
```

prints

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["term"]=>
    string(5) "termA"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "typeA"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["term"]=>
    string(5) "termB"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "typeB"
  }
  ["foo"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["term"]=>
    string(5) "termC"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "typeC"
  }
  ["bar"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["term"]=>
    string(5) "termD"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "typeD"
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone know if foo() can be done in a shorter way using built in functions?

Comment: There is the MultipleIterator and iterator_to_array(). But unfortunately MultipleIterator::key() returns an array which causes an "invalid key" error with foreach/iterator_to_array :-/ Otherwise the function would be a bit shorter (and it would rely on the order of elements as the iterator returns them instead of using the keys). Are you sure changing the parameter names isn't an option? All you'd have to do is to name them like `name="foo[0][term]"  ... name="foo[0][type]" ...foo[1][term]...foo[1][type]`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's a simple way to solve the problem using just built-in functions.

This (at least logically) should work.

```
$search_terms = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd');
$search_types = array( 1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   5);

$terms = array_fill_keys($search_terms, array());
// Loop through them once and make an array of types for each term
foreach ($search_terms as $i => $term)
    $terms[$term][] = $search_types[$i];

// Now we have $terms = array('a' => array(1),
//                            'b' => array(2),
//                            'c' => array(3, 4),
//                            'd' => array(5, 5)
//                      );

// Now run through the array again and get rid of duplicates.
foreach ($terms as $i => $types)
    $terms[$i] = array_unique($types);
```

Edit: Here's a shorter and presumably more efficient one where you end up with a less pretty array:

```
$search_terms = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd');
$search_types = array( 1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   5);

$terms = array_fill_keys($search_terms, array());
// Loop through them once and make an array of types for each term
foreach ($search_terms as $i => $term)
    $terms[$term][$search_types[$i]] = 1;

// Now we have $terms = array('a' => array(1 => 1),
//                            'b' => array(2 => 1),
//                            'c' => array(3 => 1, 4 => 1),
//                            'd' => array(5 => 1)
//                      );
```