# How to find unique elements between two sized arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array_unique with two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436146/array-unique-with-two-arrays)

How to find unique elements  between two sized arrays??

```
$array1 = array(2,1,1,3,5,5);   
$array2 = array(2,1,3,5);
```

Comment: Define 'unique elements'? Do you mean "find a value in the array that has no corresponding elements in another?"

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#PHP

Comment: What do you expect the answer to be for this question? `[2,1,3,5]`?

Comment: Can you improve on your question and ask it again .....

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want values that exist in both arrays:

```
$array1 = array(2,1,1,3,5,5);   
$array2 = array(2,1,3,5);


$array1 = array_unique($array1, SORT_NUMERIC);
$array2 = array_unique($array2, SORT_NUMERIC);
$unique = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

var_dump($unique);
```

Yields:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  int(2)
  [1] =>
  int(1)
  [3] =>
  int(3)
  [4] =>
  int(5)
}
```

---

Of course, in this example that means that `$array2` already is the answer. I am assuming that is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [array_intersect_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) plus [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) since your first array has duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "unique". I'm going to assume that you are looking for a value that appears once in all of the arrays. *Not once in each*, but once in total.

Borrowing some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933760/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-duplicated-values-from-an-array), you can do something like this -

```
$array1 = array(2,1,1,3,5,5);
$array2 = array(2,1,3,5);

$array1 = array_unique($array1);
$array2 = array_unique($array2);

$merge = array_merge($array1,$array2);

// thanks @gumbo!
$final = array_diff($merge, array_diff_assoc($merge, array_unique($merge)));
```

What will happen when we execute this code? What will be in the `$final` array? Well, taking your data, the `$final` array will be empty, because there are no unique elements between the arrays. If you drop another element in there, the `$final` array will be populated. For example -

```
$array1 = array(2,1,1,3,5,5,7);
$array2 = array(2,1,3,5);
```

In this case, `$final` will contain only the element `7`.

Comment: I think you got a little carried away by the amount of operations.

Comment: @lev - we are searching for different elements... I'm just taking the question title literally...

Comment: You still go overboard. Formatting sucks because this is a comment, but once `$array1` and `$array2` are unique:
`$unique = array_merge(
    array_diff($array1, $array2),
    array_diff($array2, $array1)
);`

Comment: By the way, the algorithm I posted in the above comment is a simple "symmetric difference".